# High performace server for 1x1 pixels (500M GET requests per day)

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, lighttpd

I need to set up a tracking server that will only serve 1x1 pixels and log all requests.
I initially thought of using Amazon's S3 or CloudFront but their costs are prohibitively high for me. I need to serve 500M pixels a day, and S3 charges $0.4 per 1M GET requests, so even without the data transfer costs I'm at $6,000/month.
I am considering setting up nginx or lighttpd on an EC2 instance. What performance should I expect with those two (e.g. per one large EC2 instance)? Are there better free products for this task?

Answer (score 4):

Nginx is indeed a good candidate for this and already has built in support for empty GIFs (see http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpEmptyGifModule).

Disk I/O will probably be the biggest issue for this server because of the access logging. The only way to figure out the performance of the different EC2 instances is to test them.

If one EC2 instance does not offer the performance you need, or if you need any redundancy for this service, you should also look into using a load balancer (either an [AWS Elastic Load Balancer](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) or your own custom one).

You could also set up multiple smaller servers in different geographical regions and use DNS latency based routing to route requests to them (use either [AWS Route 53 latency based routing](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/latency-based-multi-region-routing-now-available-for-aws.html) or another DNS solution). This would significantly reduce the connection time to your server and would distribute the load across several data centers.